# Apple Swift-Format tool for Xcode 11.4

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5, xcode11.4

Uses https://github.com/apple/swift-format after update Xcode to version 11.4 start getting error:

> "Unable to lint xxxx.swift: SwiftSyntax parser library isn't compatible."

How do we solve that issue? Changing SwiftSyntax version does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, swift-5.2-branch was created https://github.com/apple/swift-format/tree/swift-5.2-branch. The issue was solved by moving the new version of SwiftSyntax parser library.